# Visio GlueTo Method Returns "Inappropriate target object for this action"

Tags: vb.net, visio

I am trying to glue a shape to another in Visio using GlueTo

Here is the code

```
        Set trgObj = Cell.shape.Document.Masters("Trigger").Shapes(1)

        Dim x As shape            
        Set x = ActivePage.Drop(trgObj, flowConnector.CellsU("PinX"), flowConnector.CellsU("PinY"))

        Dim vsoCell1 As Visio.Cell
        Dim vsoCell2 As Visio.Cell
        Set vsoCell1 = x.CellsU("PinX")
        Set vsoCell2 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(flowConnector.ID).CellsSRC(7, 1, 0)
        vsoCell1.GlueTo vsoCell2

        'The following code I obtained through running a macro in visio
        'Dim vsoCell1 As Visio.Cell
        'Dim vsoCell2 As Visio.Cell

        'The following is the equivalent to x
        'Set vsoCell1 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(51).CellsU("PinX")

        'The following is the equivalent to flowConnector
        'Set vsoCell2 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(12).CellsSRC(7, 1, 0)
        'vsoCell1.GlueTo vsoCell2
```

it returns "Inappropriate target object for this action", but what is strange is that the code i am using I obtained from recording a macro.  I can't understand why the code works  when I record it in a macro but when I use it it doesn't.
If anyone can offer any help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem instead of using the code which was provided by the macro

```
Dim vsoCell1 As Visio.Cell
Dim vsoCell2 As Visio.Cell
Set vsoCell1 = x.CellsU("PinX")
Set vsoCell2 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(flowConnector.ID).CellsSRC(7, 1, 0)
```

rather use the following

```
Dim vsoCell1 As Visio.Cell
Dim vsoCell2 As Visio.Cell
Set vsoCell1 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(x.ID).CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 0, 0)
Set vsoCell2 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(flowConnector.ID).CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 1, 0)
```

where

```
visSectionConnectionPts, 0, 0)
```

0, 0 references cell 0 in the connection points or the x cell

and

```
visSectionConnectionPts, 1, 0)
```

references the cell 1 or y cell in the connection points